# Selecting and matching data from 3 tables

Tags: php, mysql

**SCENARIO**

x3 tables:

```
Members

    member_id | member_name
    -------------
    1  | member 1
    2  | member 2
    3  | member 3

teams

    team_id | team_name
    -------------
    1  | team 1
    2  | team 2
    3  | team 3

team_members

    team_member_id | member_id | team_id
    ------------------------------------
    1              |  1        | 1
    2              |  2        | 2
    3              |  3        | 3
```

Members can be associated with more than one team so that is why I separated the data out into 3 tables.

I want to list out all the teams, and underneath them show the members of each of those teams. I am not sure what the best approach is on this one as I am new to database design.

Currently all I am doing is outputting the two values:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM team_members";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

            echo 'teamID: <strong>' . $row["team_id"] . '</strong><br>';
            echo 'memberID: <strong>' . $row["member_id"] . '</strong><br>';

        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to `JOIN` between those tables like below, performing an `inner join` which will give only matching records. In case you want all teams irrespective of whether those teams have any member or not then consider doing a `left join` instead.

```
select t.team_id, m.member_ID, m.member_name
from teams t
left join team_mambers tm on t.team_id = tm.team_id
left join members m on m.member_ID = tm.member_ID;
```

Explanations:

Since you have a many to many relationship between teams and members; you have a relationship table where you maintain the relationship (OR Foreign keys of the tables) in a different table `team_mambers`. Thus for you to `join` `teams` with `members`; you will first have to join with the relationship table and then join with the other table `members` based on the matched id's.

I have perform a `outer join` keeping in mind that not all teams may have members in it and thus outer join will get you all the teams irrespective of members in it or not.

Comment: Hey Rahul thanks for the answer but I'm not getting any out from it?

Comment: wait  check table name near.. `left join team_members tm ` `team_mambers`

Comment: @danjbh, read the answer carefully. looks like you need to perform outer join. see edit in answer if that helps.

Comment: @Phoenix what do you mean sorry?

Comment: in your question i am seeing `team_mambers` as table name instead of `team_members` in @rahul answer. Did you correct that ?

Comment: @Rahul ok so now its outputting on `team_id` & `member_id` however the ids comes out 6 & 7 - I dont have a user of the ID of 7...

Comment: @Phoenix that was a typo in the question everything is ok in the database

Comment: @danjbh, that's the basic idea as in answer. don't understand your comment much unless you post proper data. there is no 6/7 id in your posted data.

Comment: So it looks like I am getting somewhere with this thanks to @Rahul - the issue now I have is that yes it gives me the team name and the user but I need to like group them together

Comment: @danjbh, well that's a separate question and so post it separately.

Comment: @Rahul would you mind explaining to me what the above means so I can learn?

Comment: @danjbh, see edit in answer if that gives you the clarification.

Comment: @Rahul thank you, it makes sense to me now and it will hopefully aid others too in my position.